# How to set labels in the scatter plot in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

How to give names to scatter plot in R?

For example, in the dots I want to give a player's name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/ Have a look at plotly if you want to do it interactively

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is more a question for stack overflow. Anyway, here's one possible solution, using ggplot. The `tibble` is optional, it is just a slightly different implementation of data frames. And ggrepel makes labels appear beside, and not over the dots.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

mydf <- tibble(
  player.name = c("john", "jeff", "jake"),
  average = c(36.6, 29.7, 28),
  strike.rate = c(123.5, 132.9, 136.4)
)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = average, y = strike.rate, label = player.name)) +
  geom_label_repel() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

You can also use `geom_text_repel()` instead of `geom_label_repel()`, to remove the background of the text labels and just let them appear as simple text annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `text` - maybe simpler although less pretty.

```
noms<-c("Pere","Pau","Indira","Rabindra")
x<-c(3,4,7,5)
y<-c(7,9,12,11)
plot(x,y,xlim=c(3,7.5))
text(x,y,labels=noms,pos=4)
```

[image: scatterplot with labels]

Comment: I don't see this as any less pretty then the `ggrepel` variant. `ggrepel`will probably be better, if there is a lot of names and dots.